# Fechar ou excluir a pergunta?

Tags: debate

Possuo [uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/94578/problema-entre-sistema-c-e-plugin-warsaw-gas-tecnologia) que fiz a um tempinho atrás.

O que acontece é que consegui resolver o problema que relatei. Para resolver, entrei em contato com o pessoal do suporte da empresa desenvolvedora do plugin e eles resolveram a incompatibilidade.

Mas o que eu faço agora? Excluo a pergunta ou respondo e fechamos a pergunta? Se por acaso eu excluísse, iria gerar alguma perda de conhecimento aqui no SOpt?

Comment: A solução que encontraste (que o suporte resolveu) funciona só para ti ou   achas que outros podem precisar de saber o que tu aprendeste, ou utilizar a mesma solução/plugin?

Comment: Como eles não me deram muitos detalhes do que eles fizeram pra resolver meu problema, não aprendi nada... Só sei que realmente resolveram...

Comment: Mas funciona só para ti ou achas que outros podem precisar de saber ? No caso de ser só para ti acho que podes apagar... caso seja um problema que outros podem ter podes dar uma resposta a explicar o que escreveste aqui.

Comment: Eu poderia colocar uma resposta falando o que eles me pediram para que fossem feitas as análises... Mas não sei, acho que pelo fato de eles não me darem mais informações sobre o que ocorreu, não sei se seria uma boa resposta....

Comment: Acho que você não precisa explicar a solução que você fez, mas a solução que no caso foi entrar em contato com a empresa, pois é a única forma de consertar o problema.

Comment: @Math isso daria uma boa resposta?

Comment: @ÉrikThiago acredito que sim, pois muitas pessoas não sabem que isso é possível, então apesar da solução ser específica para cada caso o único jeito de alcançá-la é entrando em contato com a empresa.

Comment: Cara, beleza! Vou formular uma resposta depois!